# Angular 13 TestBed doesn't inject interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test, angular13

I have an Angular 13 app with a custom HTTP client and an interceptor, which I want to unit test.

`base-url.interceptor.ts`:

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export const BASE_API_URL = 'BASE_API_URL';

@Injectable()
export class BaseUrlInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Inject(BASE_API_URL) private baseUrl: string) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const apiRequest = request.clone({ url: `${this.baseUrl}${request.url}` });
    return next.handle(apiRequest);
  }
}
```

`base-url.interceptor.spec.ts`:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ApiHttpService, API_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '../api-http.service';
import { BaseUrlInterceptor, BASE_API_URL } from './base-url.interceptor';

describe('BaseUrlInterceptor', () => {
  let interceptor: BaseUrlInterceptor;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        ApiHttpService,
        { provide: BASE_API_URL, value: 'http://example.com' },
        { provide: API_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BaseUrlInterceptor, multi: true }
      ]
    });
    interceptor = TestBed.inject(BaseUrlInterceptor);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(interceptor).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Unfortunately `TestBed.inject(BaseUrlInterceptor)` fails to inject an instance of the interceptor. `interceptor` is always `undefined`. If I workaround this by creating the instance manually `new BaseUrlInterceptor('http://example.com');` it works, but other interceptors have further dependencies and I want to use Angulars dependency injection here.

How can I configure the TestBed, so it can successfully create an instance of `BaseUrlInterceptor`?

I've created a minimal CodeSandbox which reproduces the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-dust-t964no?file=/src/app/base-url.interceptor.spec.ts

[image: Test sandbox]

Furthermore I get this error message, when I run the faulty test:

```
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64) BaseUrlInterceptor should be created FAILED
        Error: NG0204: unreachable
        error properties: Object({ code: 204 })
        Error: NG0204: unreachable
            at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11494:1)
            at providerToFactory (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11556:1)
            at providerToRecord (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11521:1)
            at R3Injector.processProvider (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11424:1)
            at node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11410:1
            at node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:4162:1
            at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
            at deepForEach (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:4162:1)
            at R3Injector.processInjectorType (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11410:1)
            at node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11213:1
        Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (projects/frontend/src/app/core/http/interceptors/base-url.interceptor.spec.ts:21:25)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)
Chrome Headless 98.0.4758.102 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.072 secs / 0.056 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the `Error: NG0204: unreachable` because when you're defining the provider for `BASE_API_URL` you are using a property `value` when it should be `useValue`.

```
{ provide: BASE_API_URL, useValue: 'http://example.com' },
```

Anyways, even if you fix that, you will get a `NullInjectorError` because you are not defining a provider that uses the `BaseUrlInterceptor` class as InjectionToken. You're using that class instead as one of the providers for the `API_HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` token.

In the context of unit testing the interceptor, you should get rid of the ApiHttpService, and just focus on the interceptor class.

You have two options:

**Instantiate the class manually**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    interceptor = new BaseUrlInterceptor('http://example.com');
});
```

**Or using the interceptor class as a provider in Testbed**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: BASE_API_URL, useValue: 'http://example.com' },
        BaseUrlInterceptor,
      ],
    });
    interceptor = TestBed.inject(BaseUrlInterceptor);
  });
```

cheers